# Slideshow app crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on a slideshow app. It is supposed to fade in and fade out images in an array. Somehow it works perfectly in the ios simulator but crashes on an actual device with the following error:

"slideshow[4452:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x31be52a3 0x39a7097f 0x31b2f8d9 0x97e21 0x33a0c595 0x33a4cd79 0x33a48aed 0x33a8a1e9 0x97b5f 0x33a4dad9 0x33a4d663 0x33a4584b 0x339edc39 0x339ed6cd 0x339ed11b 0x356df5a3 0x356df1d3 0x31bba173 0x31bba117 0x31bb8f99 0x31b2bebd 0x31b2bd49 0x33a44485 0x33a41301 0x97853 0x39ea7b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb) "

I am attaching my code (I do not understand what is wrong). Can anyone please help?

Implementation file:

```
    //View Controller.m

    #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    backgroundImageQueue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [backgroundImageQueue addObject:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"DSCN7419.jpg"]];
    [backgroundImageQueue addObject:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"DSCN7422.jpg"]];
    [backgroundImageQueue addObject:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"DSCN7238.jpg"]];

    /* Add any more images to the queue */
    backgroundB.image = [backgroundImageQueue
    objectAtIndex:[backgroundImageQueue count] - 1];
    [backgroundImageQueue insertObject:
    backgroundB.image atIndex:0];
    [backgroundImageQueue removeLastObject];
    backgroundA.alpha = 1.0;
    backgroundB.alpha = 0.0;
    [self nextAnimation];
    }

    -(void)nextAnimation {
    backgroundA.image = backgroundB.image;
    backgroundB.image = [backgroundImageQueue
    objectAtIndex:[backgroundImageQueue count] - 1];
    [backgroundImageQueue insertObject:
     backgroundB.image atIndex:0];
    [backgroundImageQueue removeLastObject];
    backgroundA.alpha = 1.0;
    backgroundB.alpha = 0.0;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fade" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:6];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:
     @selector(nextAnimation)];
    backgroundA.alpha = 0.0;
    backgroundB.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Header file:

```
//View Controller.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

        IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundA;
        IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundB;
        NSMutableArray *backgroundImageQueue;

}

@end
```

Comment: By any chance is the filename DSCN7419.JPG instead of DSCN7419.jpg ?

Comment: Yes, the filename is DSCN7419.JPG.

Comment: There's your answer then (see Marcelo's answer)

Comment: Nice Catch borrrden! By just changing .jpg to .JPG it now works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to insert a `nil` value into an array. That's because one of your `imageNamed:` methods returned `nil`, probably because it didn't find an image with the given name.

The different behavior on devices is because the device filesystem is case sensitive, and the simulator isn't.

Also, please format your code properly. Don't break lines unnecessarily in the middle of a method call.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo! I learned a lot about how filesystems work today! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

While inserting object `[backgroundImageQueue insertObject: backgroundB.image atIndex:0];`, check `backgroundB.image` is not nil.

```
 if (backgroundB.image != nil){
       [backgroundImageQueue insertObject: backgroundB.image atIndex:0];
 }
```